# Twilio Call to Conference vendors like webx , gotomeeting ,slack.. etc

Tags: node.js, api, twilio, phone-call, webex

i wanted a solution for a problem which includes studying about the Twilio api and SDK's which enable us to make calls,text request and can also create its own conference call , but i wanted to connect to make calls to vendor like Cisco WebEx, GoToMeeting , Slack which are really famous conference call api's , i tired searched the Twilio documentation but didn't found a solution for it how can i connect to a Cisco WebEx or any conference call by any vendor using the twilio api .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't connect directly to those APIs using the Twilio API. However, you could connect to a conference call for one of those platforms if they make available a phone number that you can dial into.

Comment: can i use SIP feature of twilio to achieve it. ?

Comment: I don't know, do they expose a SIP address that you can make calls to to join conference calls?

Comment: yes they provide SIP address , and if i have the SIP address how to i connect can you just tell me in breif?

Comment: Sure! You can connect a Twilio call to a SIP address using the [`<Sip>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip). In brief, you return a response to a Twilio webhook with `<Response><Dial><Sip>SIP_ADDRESS</Sip></Dial></Response>`.

Comment: thank you so much philnash for your responses , there is a lot of clarity now using twilio and also philnash for using SIP also i require a twilio number ?

Comment: You will likely need a number to either receive calls on and forward them or to make outgoing calls from that are then connected on to the conference.

Comment: Transfer recording per minute where the function is written in aws lambda, to aws S3 from twilio recording logs on the time the call is going on, not when the call has ended . Is it Possible ?

Comment: No, if you're recording it, you receive the full recording at the end of the call.

Comment: that means twilio will only show the recorded data in the recording logs when the current call hangs up . Can websocket help me tweak something in twilio to acheive this feature, because that is a feature i needed that would help my application vastly

Comment: The only way you could achieve this with Twilio, that I know of, is to make the Twilio side of the call a conference as well and generate a call once a minute that dials into the Twilio conference to record it and then hang up after a minute to be replaced by a new call. That way you can get recordings by the minute, you just have to do the work to make that happen.